# SWIPE (Java) works well in iOS but not in Android

Tags: java, android, ios, appium-android

I have a method SWIPE that works well with iOS but not in Android:

```
public static void swipe(String move, WebDriver driver) {
        Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        args.put("direction", move);
        JavascriptExecutor exec = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

        exec.executeScript("mobile: swipe", args);

        exec.executeScript("mobile: swipe", args);

        exec.executeScript("mobile: swipe", args);

        exec.executeScript("mobile: swipe", args);

        exec.executeScript("mobile: swipe", args);
}
```

My application is Hybrid.

Can you help me in finding the issue?

Comment: We are going to need a whole heck of a lot more information than what you provided in order to help. What does this swipe method do, what does the code look like on the server for this method, how is this code being ran? etc.

Comment: Thanks. I automate tests by using appium in iOS and Android. Swipe method scroll the UI in two directions UP and DOWN.

Comment: See my answer to the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58018656/11945234

Comment: Please,Can you give me all "imports"  or "plugins" that needs this method for be executed ?